# Alternatives to a God Class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I'm starting a new app, that will be able to connect to a lot of databases of different providers at the same time.

Thinking in a pattern to use all the connections with ease, i made this code (C++):

```
class Bd
{
    private:
    TUniConnection* mpConnection;

    public:
    Bd::Bd()
    {
        mpConnection = new TUniConnection(NULL);
    }

    void Bd::setProvider(UnicodeString provider)
    {
        mpConnection->ProviderName = provider;
    }

    void Bd::connect()
    {
        mpConnection->Connect();
    }

    UnicodeString Bd::getProvider() const
    { return mpConnection->ProviderName; }

    Bd::~Bd()
    { delete mpConnection; }
};

// In the right path to become a singleton-helper-utility-god-class
class App
{
    public:
    // Default bd. Just a shortcut.
    Bd* bd;

    App()
    { bd = getBd("BDMain"); }

    ~App()
    { delBd("BDMain"); }

    Bd* getBd(UnicodeString key)
    {
        if(mpBdList[key] != NULL)
        {
            return mpBdList[key];
        }
        mpBdList[key] = new Bd;
        return mpBdList[key];
    }

    void delBd(UnicodeString key)
    {
        delete mpBdList[key];
        mpBdList[key] = NULL;
    }

    private:
    std::map<UnicodeString, Bd *>mpBdList;
};

// Just an example of use.
int main()
{
    // Consider this instance global/singleton/etc
    App* app = new App;
    app->bd->setProvider("Oracle");
    app->connect();

    // Outside the main, probably in some form (this method don't exist - yet)
    app->bd->query("blah blah blah");

    app->getBd("settings")->setProvider("SQLite");
    app->getBd("settings")->connect();
    app->getBd("settings")->query("blah blah blah");
}
```

Obviously doesn't work yet, but you guys can have a clue of my thought.
Theorically, looks perfect.
I can access the main connection (app->bd) with ease and short code. The same with other connections.
Even perfect to me, everybody is saying that is anti-pattern and all.

How can i achieve the almost same result, without this "helper" class, and still able to share my connections/settings to all forms and classes, without passing nothing to parameters/constructors.

thanks.

Comment: You don't need any of your calls to new. Just create objects on the stack. E.g. `App app;` or `std::map<UnicodeString, Bd> mpBdList;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make `mpBdList` a static private member of `Bd`, and similarly make `getBd`, `delBd` static methods of `Bd`.  Then you don't need `App` at all and you're still adhering to the one concept, one class dictum.  I'm sure there are many other valid ways to set up things as well.

Comment: Looks interesting, i will try. But this don't look 'general' to me, i still have the feeling that sooner or later the god class will be needed to something else, or i will have to #include the 'Bd.h' around all files. ;/

Comment: @Stew Well even as it is, `Bd` will have to be included pretty much everywhere--`App` as written looks like it could get by with just a forward declaration of `Bd`, but anywhere you want to call one of `Bd`'s methods, class `Bd` will have to be part of the `#include` chain.